# Set Specific Variables in Swift

Tags: swift, inheritance

I am learning Swift Code using the book "Swift Code for Beginners" by Pitre.  I have a problem with one statement that is not adequately described in the book.

In formulating how to set up a simple app, the author begins by creating a new target file called SimpleInterest.swift  That file contains the following statements:

```
import Foundation

class SimpleInterest{
    func calculate(loanAmount:Double, var interestRate:Double,years:Int) -> Double{
        interestRate  = interestRate/100.00
        var interest = Double(years) * interestRate * loanAmount
        return loanAmount + interest
    }
}
```

In the main file AppDelegate.swift, he then sets up the following code:

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!  
    @IBOutlet weak var loanAmountField:NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var interestRateField:NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var yearsField:NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var resultField:NSTextField!


    var simpleInterestCalculator:SimpleInterest  = SimpleInterest

    @IBAction func buttonClicked(sender:NSButton) {
        var result:Double
        result = simpleInterestCalculator.calculate(loanAmountField.doubleValue, 
                     interestRate:interestRateField.doubleValue,
                     years:yearsField.integerValue)

        self.resultField.stringValue = result.description
    }

}
```

My problem is with the statement:

```
var simpleInterestCalculator:SimpleInterest  =  SimpleInterest()
```

I am not sure why we cannot simple state:

```
var simpleInterestCalculator  = SimpleInterest()
```

since SimpleInterest is already part of the package.  What am I missing?

Is this some sort of a shortcut for inheritance expressed by the following code:

```
AnotherSimpleInterestClass : SimpleInterest{
    var simpleInterestCalculator  = AnotherSimpleInterestClass()
}
```

Comment: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch03.html#_variable_declaration

Answer (score 1):

No; the `:` operator has various meanings depending on the context.

The inheritance denotation you mention at the end is one type; a `:` signifies the class(es) that your current class extends.

However, in the case of `var simpleInterestCalculator: SimpleInterest = SimpleInterest`, *it is merely denoting **type***.

That is, `simpleInterestCalculator` is of type `SimpleInterest`, which you defined in the `SimpleInterest` class; you then assign the result of constructing a `SimpleInterest` object to that variable.

Other examples:

```
var testStr: String = "Test" // Type String
var testInt: Int = 5 // Type Int
var controller: UIViewController = UIViewController() // Type UIViewController
```

Answer (score 1):

The colon and type after the variable name is explicitly defining the class type of the object instance. Swift has the ability to infer this from the assigned value so technically you are correct, it is unnecessary, but not invalid.

```
var myString:String = "my string"
```

is exactly the same as

```
var myString = "my string"
```

Answer (score 1):

The author of the book you are learning with simply likes more verbose syntax. The compiler will infer the correct type, and eliminate the need for the redundant variable type declaration: try without explicit typing, you'll find that it makes no difference whatsoever.

Typing explicitly in Swift can be useful if there may be an ambiguity. In this case, there is none so the intention is probably purely pedagogical.

```
var thing: Thing = Thing() 
//is strictly equivalent to
var thing = Thing()

// but typing explicitly would make sense here:
var derivedThing: Thing = DerivedThing()
//if DerivedThing inherits from Thing, of course!
```

Comment: There is more to specifying types than verbosity; if it were useless, Apple wouldn't have included it. Oftentimes, specifying type helps prevent what would be terribly annoying errors.

Comment: I think you misread my answer. Not trying to suggest that explicit typing is useless, but in that particular case of chaining var declaration, type and instantiation of identical type, it is redundant and probably pedagogical.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to all the people who answered this question.  Here is what I have been able to deduce:

1. If anyone else is using the book "Swift Code for Beginners" by Pitre, you will be helped by the study of "Metatype" types in Apple Developer Documentation at this link:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-ID445

2. Basically, a type designation can consist of a class, structure, enumeration or protocol as well as those discussed in the book.  If you wish, you can add the type designation to any of the classes created in several chapters.
3. Concerning the question above:

   ```
   var simpleInterestCalculator:SimpleInterest  = SimpleInterest
   ```

is equivalent to:

```
var simpleInterestCalculator  = SimpleInterest
```

3. This feature is not discussed in the book.